# What data type should WebClassError be passed as in vb6

Tags: vb6

I have the following function in my Dsr in vb6 ...

```
...
   Private Sub WebClass_FatalErrorResponse(SendDefault As Boolean)  
       myGenericFatalErrorResponse Error  
   End Sub

private sub myGenericFatalErrorResponse(byval oError as WebClassError)  
...  
end sub
```

Gives Error :-

```
myGenericFatalErrorResponse Error fails due to type mismatch .
```

So my Question is what should Error be passed as in `myGenericFatalErrorResponse`, I am currently just passing `"as variant"` but feel like `"as WebClassError"` should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `err.raise`.

Remember if a COM Object raises an error it must do it right. Return 8004nnnn errors for vb errors and 8007nnnn for Window's errors. You can translate error numbers but always leave source alone.

Other modules rely on you raising an error.

From VBScript's help (same as VB6's help but less clicks to get to on my computer)

Generates a run-time error.

**object.Raise(number, source, description, helpfile, helpcontext)**

**Arguments**

```
object
```

*Always the Err object*.

**number**

A Long integer subtype that identifies the nature of the error. VBScript errors (both VBScript-defined and user-defined errors) are in the range 0–65535.

**source**

A string expression naming the object or application that originally generated the error. When setting this property for an Automation object, use the form project.class. If nothing is specified, the programmatic ID of the current VBScript project is used.

**description**

A string expression describing the error. If unspecified, the value in number is examined. If it can be mapped to a VBScript run-time error code, a string provided by VBScript is used as description. If there is no VBScript error corresponding to number, a generic error message is used.

**helpfile**

The fully qualified path to the Help file in which help on this error can be found. If unspecified, VBScript uses the fully qualified drive, path, and file name of the VBScript Help file.

**helpcontext**

The context ID identifying a topic within helpfile that provides help for the error. If omitted, the VBScript Help file context ID for the error corresponding to the number property is used, if it exists.

**Remarks**

All the arguments are optional except number. If you use Raise, however, without specifying some arguments, and the property settings of the Err object contain values that have not been cleared, those values become the values for your error.

When setting the number property to your own error code in an Automation object, you add your error code number to the constant vbObjectError. For example, to generate the error number 1050, assign vbObjectError + 1050 to the number property.

The following example illustrates use of the Raise method.

```
On Error Resume Next

Err.Raise 6  ' Raise an overflow error.

MsgBox ("Error # " & CStr(Err.Number) & " " & Err.Description)

Err.Clear    ' Clear the error.
```